# Regex repeat search without truncating

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find strings which have a character, followed by another character, and then followed by the first character.

For example, in "abab" I want "aba" and "bab"

```
/([a-z])[a-z]{1}\1/g
```

However, executing this script gives me only the first result (specifically I'm using javascript)

```
"abab".match(/([a-z])[a-z]{1}\1/g)
["aba"]
```

Where as this gives me two instead of three (Should get "aba", "bab", "bcb")

```
"ababcb".match(/([a-z])[a-z]{1}\1/g)
["aba", "bcb"]
```

I believe this is because the regex repeats itself on the truncated string, so it'll find the first match, and then execute the regex on the remaining string. How can I avoid this and get all possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Positive Lookahead to capture:

```
var re = /(?=(([a-z])[a-z]\2))./g, matches = [];
while (m = re.exec('abab')) {
   matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches) //=> [ 'aba', 'bab' ]
```

---

```
var re = /(?=(([a-z])[a-z]\2))./g, matches = [];
while (m = re.exec('ababcb')) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches) //=> [ 'aba', 'bab', 'bcb' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
var re = /(\w)(?=(\w\1))/g;
var input="abab";
var matches = [];

while (match = re.exec(input)) {
   matches.push( match[1] + match[2] );
}

console.log(matches);
//=> ["aba", "bab"]
```

**2nd Example:**

```
input="ababcb";
matches = [];    
while (match = re.exec(input)) {
   matches.push( match[1] + match[2] );
}

console.log(matches);
//=> ["aba", "bab", "bcb"]
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lQ8dT6/2)

Comment: I managed to simplify the regex to `/(\w)(?=(\w\1))/g` [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xA0nH0/1)

Comment: Thanks @RevanProdigalKnight, good one. I updated answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @anubhava you could of avoided using slice/join here.